# JQuery | Add anchor and add / remove class on click

Tags: jquery

Here is my jquery:

```
// Show all instances
    var link = $('<a class="show-instances" href="#">Show all instances</a>');

    $('tr.main').hide().first().find('.product').parent().remove('a').append(link);
    $('tr.main').first().show();

    $(function () {
        $(".show-instances").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".show-instances").addClass('selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
            var selectedClass = $(this).closest('tr.main').attr('class').split(' ');
            $('.' + selectedClass[1]).not(':has("a.show-instances")').toggle();
            return false;
        })
    });
```

Adding the anchor works and on click adding the class works - I just don't understand why on click the class added "selected" won't remove when a user clicks the anchor the 2nd time?

So when a user clicks the anchor "show-instances" class "selected" will add to the anchor - I need the class to be removed when it's clicked again.

Am I missing another function?

Any suggestions?

/***************RESOLVED******************/

Using the Toggle class - here is the jquery:

```
// Show all instances
    var link = $('<a class="show-instances" href="#">Show all instances</a>');

    $('tr.main').hide().first().find('.product').parent().remove('a').append(link);
    $('tr.main').first().show();

    $(function () {
        $(".show-instances").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
            var selectedClass = $(this).closest('tr.main').attr('class').split(' ');
            $('.' + selectedClass[1]).not(':has("a.show-instances")').toggle();
            return false;
        })
    });
```

Also here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MV4uM/) link to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you're describing perhaps the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function would work better for you.

From the API documentation:

> .toggleClass( function(index, class, switch) [, switch] )
>   function(index, class, switch)A function that returns class names to
>   be toggled in the class attribute of each element in the matched set.
>   Receives the index position of the element in the set, the old class
>   value, and the switch as arguments. switchA boolean value to determine
>   whether the class should be added or removed.

Although this one seems pretty straightforward, it can also help if you post these type of questions up on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so people can see what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah I generally do but didn't think it was needed - will edit the post with solution to Jsfiddle link :-)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `toggleClass()` instead of **removing** and **adding** classes ?